# JavaScript addEventListener delay

Tags: javascript, accelerometer, addeventlistener

I'm building a mobile application using JavaScript. Into it i need to obtain data from phones' accelerometer, so I attach an event listener to it:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function (event) {
        if (typeof(event.alpha) != 'undefined') {
            //here goes function for an event
        }
    }, false);
}
```

But the problem is that it obtains data every millisecond, thus when i call the function to draw and redraw something according to this data, it keeps doing it each millisecond -> application crashes.

Is there any way to delay, or to receive this data in a smaller portions? Is there a function to listen to an event, for example, each half a second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "function debouncing". Basically, you execute your stuff only once in a certain amount of time. A simple implementation would be:

```
var lastExecution;
addEventListener("deviceorientation", function (event) {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (now - lastExecution < 17) return; // ~60Hz
    lastExecution = now;
    ...
}, false);
```

(Yes, `lastExecution` is undefined at first. It's fine.)

Comment: If you have problems with the undefined, you could simple give it `0` as startvalue

Comment: @Martijn Yes, but... the would be a problem if the date is before 1970 :) Oh well, but `undefined` may give an obscure result but it's fine anyway.

Comment: It wasn't meant as comment on your code, only to give a solution for those who consider it a problem :)

Comment: BTW, I hardly doubt anyone will be using this piece of code before 1970 :p

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like detrottle/debounce

If you have jQuery, [these guys made it easy](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/):

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function (event) {
    $.throttle( 250, function (event){
        // Code here will excecute every 250 ms
    })
 );
```

Comment: jQuery has never been mentioned.

Comment: Throttling is absolutely independent from jQuery. That "plugin" only does put the common functionality in the `$` namespace, for whatever purpose; but doesn't have much to do with jQuery.

Comment: Fine, rephrazed it to indicate it's jQuery, without suggesting dethrottle is jQuery only.